# Call Method Once Flip Is Done - jQuery-Flip

Tags: jquery

I am using a [Flip](https://nnattawat.github.io/flip/) Plugin

I have been trying to call a method once the flip is done/completed,
but the method is getting called even before the flip is done.completed.

```
$("#card").flip('toggle');
$("#card").on("done", ChangeWord());
```

Let me know where i am going wrong ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i have no clue how to use it flip:done right  ? i couldn't dint any documentation  on it

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Not required to go to the _Events_ section, there is indeed a `callback` option.

Comment: @HudhaifaYoosuf I added an answer to show you how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is in the link you posted in the question under the 'Events' heading. Specifically, the `flip:done` event. Also note that you need to pass the reference of the `ChangeWord()` function to the event handler, not its return value. Try this:

```
$("#card").on('flip:done', ChangeWord).flip('toggle');
```

Alternatively the `flip()` method accepts a callback function to be executed when the animation completes:

```
$("#card").flip('toggle', ChangeWord);
```

Comment: `$("#card").flip('toggle', ChangeWord);` this worked out fine as this will happen only when i use it , but `$("#card").on('flip:done', ChangeWord).flip('toggle');` will call the method every time it flips

Comment: That's right. Either will work for you, it just depends on your needs.